# Search URL gives 404

Tags: pagination, search

I have search URL that looks like this

```
/?s=term //this works
```

But when I click on a pagination link to go to second page I get this

```
/page/2/?s=term //this gives 404
```

When I manually enter this URL

```
/?s=term&paged=2 //this also works
```

So any idea how to solve this?

Comment: What are your permalink settings? Do you have any custom rewrite rules (like .htaccess on Apache? Plugins that affect permalinks? A custom post type "page"?

Comment: .htaccess is default for WordPress. I've removed all rewrite rules and flushed rewrite rules. Funny thing it works on localhost but not on dev server. Permalink structure is custom and it's `/blog/%postname%/`.
Although I have CPT with this parameter `'rewrite' => array('slug' => '/', 'with_front' => false)` but again it works on localhost